# Not working added global header parameters using Swagger 3 UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I have migrated existing project Swagger to Swagger3 using dependency springdoc-openapi-ui 1.6.8 version .
Getting issue while added the global header parameter in Swagger config file, it was not showing at Swagger dashboard
Please advised me if any issue in mentioned code.

Code:

**

```
@Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes("basicScheme",
                                new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP).scheme("basic"))
                        .addParameters("myHeader1",
                                new Parameter().in("header").schema(new StringSchema()).name("myHeader1"))
                        .addHeaders("myHeader2",
                                new Header().description("myHeader2 header").schema(new StringSchema())))
                .info(new Info().title("eWallet API Sandbox").description("eWallet API Sandbox").version("v1.0")
                        .contact(new Contact().name("WOW Finstack").url("https://wowdigital.ai/")
                                .email("info@wowdigital.ai"))
                        .termsOfService("WOW Finstack").license(new License().name("License").url("#")));
        //
    };
```

**

Dependency :

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded to `springdoc-openapi-ui` and struggled a bit to make global headers work on Spring boot `2.6.3`.

I managed to make global header work if it's defined as a `Parameter` (using `new Parameter()...`) but I did not make it work when defined as a `Header` (using `new Header()...`)

I guess that you already defined a `GroupedOpenApi` Spring Bean. So what you have to do is add a `OpenApiCustomizer` to this `GroupedOpenApi`, see `addOpenApiCustomizer(globalHeaderCustomizer())` below:

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi publicGroup() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
        .packagesToScan("com.my.package")
        .pathsToMatch("/**")
        .group("public")
        .addOpenApiCustomizer(globalHeaderCustomizer()) // --> you need this!
        .build();
}
```

where `globalHeaderCustomizer()` is:

```
private OpenApiCustomizer globalHeaderCustomizer() {
    return openApi -> openApi.getPaths().values().stream().flatMap(pathItem -> pathItem.readOperations().stream())
        .forEach(operation -> operation.addParametersItem(
            new HeaderParameter().$ref("#/components/parameters/myHeader1")));
}
```

I think that should fix your issue.